# How to include d3.js in angularjs app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am writing one Angularjs app. I am using MEAN stack with Grunt. I have written one directive that uses d3 library. I have d3.js file in the following location:

`/client/app/lib/d3.js`

The file is automatically included in the index.html and it runs fine in development mode. But when I run it in production mode I get the following error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined`

Then I did some R&D and found that if any java script file is included with the following syntax it gives same error:

```
!function foo() {
   var myd3 = {};
...
...
...
   this.myd3 = myd3;
}();
```

The above code will give error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: myd3 is not defined`

Comment: Have you seen [this post](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't return anything from a function explicitly, `undefined` is returned. Now the `!` makes it `true`. That's all.

I think the problem is execution of scripts. Are you sure that `d3` is loaded first before it is utilized anywhere in your project ? Make sure `<script src='d3.js'></script>` is present before your code scripts.

Generally, for production grade code, `concatenation` of scripts is done. Make sure that the concatenation is done in order (d3, your-app-scripts).

Comment: Thank you for reply.  Yes the <script src='d3.js'></script> is present in index.html. It is not just d3.js I wrote a small a.js file as follows: !function(){ var a; this.a = a}(); It also throws the same error.  How can I confirm that concatenation is done in order ? Sorry for silly question. I am new to 
Angular.js app.

Comment: how did you start building the angular app ? are you using yeoman or some build config of your own ? give the build config..

Comment: Yes I am using yeoman and fullstack-generator to generate the code. I have not written any build config.

Comment: please go through the concat task.. how its run. Go through the plugin documentation. It will help a lot.